# MySQL query performance issue with MyISAM table

Tags: mysql, performance

Folks

I have a table( billing_data) with about 60 million records. The table engine is MyISAM. We have a stored procedure that will read csv file and dump in temp table  every 10-15 mins and then it  will be inserted in this table( billing_data). There are lot of records being inserted in this table.

we are trying to run the query as below on the same table( plus the other tables in join) to generate the report.

```
"select b.destination,b.release_cause_protocol_stack,b.binary_value_protocol_stack,b.release_cause from billing_datas b inner join (select id from carriermasters where id in (99, 100, 101) ) c1 on b.carrierid_customer=c1.idinner join (select id from technicalprofiles where id in (83, 274, 84, 416)) t1 on b.technical_profileid_customer=t1.id  inner join (select trunk from trunks where trunk in (90409, 90310, 30230, 30313) ) tr1 on b.origination_trunkid=tr1.trunk inner join (select id from carriermasters where id in (214, 215, 59, 60, 62, 292, 63, 216, 64, 61, 217, 274, 58) ) c2 on b.carrierid_supplier=c2.id  inner join (select id from technicalprofiles where id in (223, 55, 224, 56, 225, 57, 226, 58, 227, 228, 229, 230, 393, 394, 395, 59, 231, 232, 233, 460, 234)) t2 on b.technical_profileid_supplier=t2.id inner join (select trunk from trunks where trunk in (90106, 30249, 90249, 30250, 90250, 90445, 30409, 90446, 30410, 30294, 90363, 30293, 90293, 30175, 30146, 90146, 90435, 90049, 30177, 90294, 90130, 30130, 90189, 30145, 90145, 90389, 30400, 90429, 90121, 90159)) tr2 on b.supplierid=tr2.trunk where b.start_time_date between '2013-08-02 00:00:00' and '2013-08-02 23:59:59' order by b.start_time_date asc"
```

NOw the scenario is

a) if we stop the cron job to insert the data in the billing_datas table, then the above query takes about more than 40 mins.

b) if the cron job is running ( inserting the data from the file) to the temp table and then to billing_data. At that time the above query will run forever.

I m not sure where i m getting wrong.

we also checked the indexes and its fine.

Mysql query :  show variables

---

```
automatic_sp_privileges ON
back_log    50
big_tables  OFF

binlog_cache_size   32768
binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates OFF
binlog_format   STATEMENT
bulk_insert_buffer_size 8388608
completion_type 0
concurrent_insert   1
connect_timeout 10
default_week_format 0
delay_key_write ON
delayed_insert_limit    100
delayed_insert_timeout  300
delayed_queue_size  1000
div_precision_increment 4
engine_condition_pushdown   ON
event_scheduler OFF
flush   OFF
flush_time  0
foreign_key_checks  ON
ft_query_expansion_limit    20
ignore_builtin_innodb   OFF
innodb_adaptive_hash_index  ON
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size 1048576
innodb_autoextend_increment 8
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode    1
innodb_buffer_pool_size 8388608
innodb_checksums    ON
innodb_commit_concurrency   0
innodb_concurrency_tickets  500
innodb_data_file_path   ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir    
innodb_doublewrite  ON
innodb_fast_shutdown    1
innodb_file_io_threads  4
innodb_file_per_table   OFF
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  1
innodb_flush_method 
innodb_force_recovery   0
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    50
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  OFF
innodb_log_buffer_size  1048576
innodb_log_file_size    5242880
innodb_log_files_in_group   2
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct  90
innodb_max_purge_lag    0
innodb_mirrored_log_groups  1
innodb_open_files   300
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  OFF
innodb_stats_method nulls_equal
innodb_stats_on_metadata    ON
innodb_support_xa   ON
innodb_sync_spin_loops  20
innodb_table_locks  ON
innodb_thread_concurrency   8
innodb_thread_sleep_delay   10000
innodb_use_legacy_cardinality_algorithm ON
insert_id   0
interactive_timeout 28800
join_buffer_size    131072
keep_files_on_create    OFF
key_buffer_size 8384512
key_cache_age_threshold 300
key_cache_block_size    1024
key_cache_division_limit    100
large_files_support ON
large_page_size 0
large_pages OFF
last_insert_id  0
local_infile    ON
locked_in_memory    OFF
log OFF
log_bin OFF
log_bin_trust_function_creators OFF
log_bin_trust_routine_creators  OFF
long_query_time 10
low_priority_updates    OFF
max_allowed_packet  1048576
max_binlog_cache_size   1.84467E+19
max_binlog_size 1073741824
max_connect_errors  10
max_connections 151
max_delayed_threads 20
max_error_count 64
max_heap_table_size 16777216
max_insert_delayed_threads  20
max_join_size   1.84467E+19
max_length_for_sort_data    1024
max_long_data_size  1048576
max_prepared_stmt_count 16382
max_relay_log_size  0
max_seeks_for_key   1.84467E+19
max_sort_length 1024
max_sp_recursion_depth  0
max_tmp_tables  32
max_user_connections    0
max_write_lock_count    1.84467E+19
min_examined_row_limit  0
multi_range_count   256
myisam_data_pointer_size    6
myisam_max_sort_file_size   9.22337E+18
myisam_mmap_size    1.84467E+19
myisam_recover_options  OFF
myisam_repair_threads   1
myisam_sort_buffer_size 8388608
myisam_stats_method nulls_unequal
myisam_use_mmap OFF
net_buffer_length   16384
net_read_timeout    30
net_retry_count 10
net_write_timeout   60
open_files_limit    1024
optimizer_prune_level   1
optimizer_search_depth  62
optimizer_switch    index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on
preload_buffer_size 32768
pseudo_thread_id    7256
query_alloc_block_size  8192
query_cache_limit   1048576
query_cache_min_res_unit    4096
query_cache_size    0
query_cache_type    ON
query_cache_wlock_invalidate    OFF
query_prealloc_size 8192
range_alloc_block_size  4096
read_buffer_size    131072
read_only   OFF
read_rnd_buffer_size    262144
skip_external_locking   ON
slow_launch_time    2
sort_buffer_size    2097144
sql_auto_is_null    ON
sql_big_selects ON
sql_big_tables  OFF
sql_buffer_result   OFF
sql_log_bin ON
sql_log_off OFF
sql_log_update  ON
sql_low_priority_updates    OFF
sql_max_join_size   1.84467E+19
sql_quote_show_create   ON
sql_safe_updates    OFF
sql_select_limit    1.84467E+19
storage_engine  MyISAM
sync_binlog 0
sync_frm    ON
table_definition_cache  256
table_lock_wait_timeout 50
table_open_cache    64
table_type  MyISAM
thread_cache_size   0
thread_handling one-thread-per-connection
thread_stack    262144
timed_mutexes   OFF
tmp_table_size  16777216
transaction_alloc_block_size    8192
transaction_prealloc_size   4096
unique_checks   ON
updatable_views_with_limit  YES
version 05/01/69
version_compile_os  redhat-linux-gnu
wait_timeout    28800
```

Comment: Post the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT <your query>`. "we also checked the indexes and its fine." - really? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT b.destination
     , b.release_cause_protocol_stack
     , b.binary_value_protocol_stack
     , b.release_cause 
  FROM billing_datas b 
  JOIN carriermasters customer
    ON b.carrierid_customer = customer.id
  JOIN technicalprofiles tpc 
    ON b.technical_profileid_customer = tpc.id  
  JOIN trunks kc 
    ON b.origination_trunkid = kc.trunk 
  JOIN carriermasters supplier 
    ON b.carrierid_supplier = supplier.id  
  JOIN technicalprofiles tps
    ON b.technical_profileid_supplier = tps.id 
  JOIN trunks ks 
    ON b.supplierid = ks.trunk 
 WHERE b.start_time_date BETWEEN '2013-08-02 00:00:00' AND '2013-08-02 23:59:59' 
   AND customer.id IN (99, 100, 101) 
   AND tpc.id IN (83, 274, 84, 416)
   AND kc.trunk IN (90409, 90310, 30230, 30313) 
   AND supplier.id IN (214, 215, 59, 60, 62, 292, 63, 216, 64, 61, 217, 274, 58) 
   AND tps.id IN (223, 55, 224, 56, 225, 57, 226, 58, 227, 228, 229, 230, 393, 394, 395, 59, 231, 232, 233, 460, 234)
   AND ks.trunk IN (90106, 30249, 90249, 30250, 90250, 90445, 30409, 90446, 30410, 30294, 90363, 30293, 90293, 30175, 30146, 90146, 90435, 90049, 30177, 90294, 90130, 30130, 90189, 30145, 90145, 90389, 30400, 90429, 90121, 90159)
 ORDER  
    BY b.start_time_date ASC;
```

Comment: hey strawberry, the above query works perfect it takes about 9 mins if we have a scenario A . we still have a performance issue with the query if we follow scenario B . can we do some optimization in the mysql system variables to make it fast.

Comment: For help with that you need to provide an EXPLAIN